# Is "leave out to dry" an accepted variation of "hang out to dry"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Earlier this week, I told someone, *I would never intentionally leave you out to dry*. I realize, just now, that the more common idiom is *hang you out to dry*.

Is the first one also acceptable? is it common? or is it preferable (and more correct) to use the latter? Beneath is a good definition of the idiom.

> [hang someone out to dry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hang_someone_out_to_dry)
>
> Leave someone in a difficult or vulnerable situation.

If the variation *leave out to dry* is indeed acceptable, then I would be interested in any instances of this variation from respected sources.

Comment: *Leave* is too passive (i.e. inactive) for this expression.  The expression needs to convey ill intent.  *Hang you out to try* accomplishes this. // If you find some instances of "leave out to dry," it could be imprecise speaking, or it could be confusion with "leave hanging."

Comment: @aparente001 I don't think that *hang out to dry* necessarily conveys ill-intent. I think it could simply convey selfishness. Admittedly, this is a form of ill intent but it certainly is not spite or malice.

Comment: @aparente001 For example, a man who ditches his co-worker in the middle of a project to go on a weekend vacation with his girlfriend might be hanging his co-worker out to dry. Selfish, yes. Malicious? No.

Comment: I think you might be amalgamating with "leaving someone high and dry."  I'm not saying that in the right context you would not be understood if you said "leave someone out to dry," but it would bother certain listeners (the nitpicky type, like me).

Comment: *Acceptable*? To whom? Opinion-based.

Comment: @aparente001 Ah, you switched the topic. I was responding to your point that *hang out to dry* does not necessarily imply ill intent, and gave an example to illustrate my point.

Comment: @Drew - I wouldn't close a question that is asking if a variant of an idiom is correct.

Comment: @ktm5124 - The bottom line is that I think that *leave out to dry* is not equivalent to *hang out to dry*.  Have you found anything to document your hunch?  I looked, and did not.

Comment: @aparente001 I never claimed that they were equivalent. The expression *leave out to dry* is not even idiomatic, as the answers to my question clearly indicate. Let us forget about *leave out to dry* for the meantime. I am simply contesting your point that the established idiom, *hang out to dry*, necessarily implies ill intent, to use your words.

Comment: @ktm5124 - Well, if you're not asking whether your proposed variant *leave out to dry* is an acceptable equivalent to *hang out to dry*, then what are you asking?

Comment: @aparente001 That was my main question, which has already been answered. You commented on this question, saying that *hang out to dry* implies ill intent. I am holding you accountable for what you said: I think you are wrong. Why do you keep avoiding this (follow-up) question?

Comment: @ktm5124 - Apparently, I was just tilting at windmills -- trying to convince you that "leave out to dry" isn't idiomatically equivalent.  Now that you've clarified that you're already convinced, you can disregard my comment, which may have come out too strong.  I was just trying to provide a rationalization for one version working as an idiom and the other not working.

Comment: @aparente001 That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were mixing and matching two different idioms

**Leave you hanging** is one idiom that now appears far more used than "hang out to dry"  ... if ngram works that is.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leave+you+hanging%2C+hang+you+out+to+dry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleave%20you%20hanging%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chang%20you%20out%20to%20dry%3B%2Cc0

Cambridge dictionary

> [**leave someone hanging**:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/leave-someone-hanging)
>   ​
>
> to keep someone waiting for your decision or answer:
>
> *I was left hanging, waiting for the college to tell me whether I got a scholarship or not.*

Leaving someone hanging evokes more clinging to a liferope or a ledge to me...but perhaps it shared the same laundry root ? : )

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem *'leave someone out to dry'* is an acceptable variant of *'hang someone out to dry'.* While the Google Ngram Viewer does not find any n-grams for the former version, it shows that the latter version of the idiom is in standard use.  [image]

A discussion about ***'leave someone out to dry'*** can be seen  on the [WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/leave-out-to-dry.2462680/)

Comment: Perhaps it's vernacular but not written down? That would explain the WordReference discussion and the Ngram results.

Comment: You get slightly better [examples in the past tense](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=left+out+to+dry%2Chung+out+to+dry&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleft%20out%20to%20dry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chung%20out%20to%20dry%3B%2Cc0) (though still with no noun or pronoun)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if you leave someone "hanging out to dry" - you leave them to take all the blame, when it may not be their fault.
eg A manager asks an employee to do something, there is no record of the manager asking the employee to do this. The thing goes wrong and is a disaster. In the investigation, the manager denies knowing anything about it, and all the blame falls on the employee. We say "the employee has been hung out to dry". 
It is often the same when a plane crashes - the manufacturer blames the dead pilot - the pilot is "hung out to dry".
Looking at many web articles on this, as stated above by ktm5124, there is confusion between this and "being left high and dry"