# Need softer, less potentially offensive word for "malapropism"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary, idiom-requests, tone

**Background**: My spouse is German, and tends to misuse some words in English, and also tends to get some idioms a bit garbled.  For example, to my spouse, "school" is synonymous with "grade school," and does not include college (but the distortion of this English vocabulary item isn't 100% consistent).  So it's hard to know what is meant by, for example, "S. (21yo son) is doing a lot better with understanding underlying concepts [in science] than he was doing when he was in school."  This is confusing because S. graduated college in May.  Is the improvement since May?  Or since graduating high school four years ago?  Hard to know!  My spouse gets idioms garbled too, but I can't think of an example right now.

**Problem**: There was a [recent question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/380335/112436) that reminded me of my spouse's malapropisms, but I hesitated to use this word in a comment to the OP, since it might feel offensive.  Is there a softer, but similar, word or phrase I could use instead of saying (after some going around and around with the OPE), "*Leave out to dry*, used in place of *hang out to dry*, sounds like a malapropism, pure and simple."  (I'd like some help expressing this, whether or not you agree with me about that particular idiom.)

For reference, here's a definition of *malapropism*, from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/malapropism):

> 1.
>   an act or habit of misusing words ridiculously, especially by the confusion of words that are similar in sound.
>
> 2.
>   an instance of this, as in, “Lead the way and we'll precede.”

Comment: We may need to know why you consider *malapropism* to be offensive. (I don't think "leave out to dry" instead of "hang out to dry" is necessarily a malapropism in the same way that (2) definitely is -- part of the effect of a real malapropism is that the word actually used directly conflicts with the intention.) Also: your spouse may be confused between the German system of schooling and your indigenous system (US?). Certainly I (in the UK) have never understood how US "schools" work.

Comment: I think saying somthing like "That's not the way that word is normally understood here", or "i'm afraid people would misunderstand what you meant by that in xyz"(your community) That sort of explanation might be better than looking for a formal term... unless someone can think of a friendly, informal way (which is what you're looking for of course! ; ) )

Comment: On the specific matter of *school*, my understanding is that the British reserve this term for elementary and secondary education, whereas Americans apply it to any formal academic institution. Along similar lines, *pupil* is preferred to *student* for lower levels, but it is somewhat quaint in AmE, which has no qualms about *kindergarten students*.

Comment: I am not sure that malapropism is an offensive term.

Comment: Malapropism is offensive in that it comes across as lecturing and judgmental ... formal words have that negative effect whether we like it or not.  If the goal is to have a productive conversation, the precise word might not be the best word

Comment: @Tom22 Correcting someone's grammar often comes across as judgemental and pedantic irrespective of the phrasing.

Comment: Maybe it is the truth and being blunt about it that is offensive, not the words themselves. You probably just want replacements for ''mistake' and 'error' and 'wrong', want to euphemize. 'inappropriate', 'just not the way it is said', 'misleading', 'false friend', 'semantic slippage' are in the direction of removing blame from the user.

Comment: I think that what might cause offense is the fact that we laugh *at* Mrs. Malaprop.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I've explained the U.S. system and the meaning of the term "school" until I'm blue in the face.  And our children attend school in the U.S.  In the referenced question, I repeated myself several times.  Did you look at the referenced question?  There seemed to be some confusion of several idioms that shared one or more words.  That's what reminded me of malapropism.  Although you're right, it wasn't quite the same, and it wasn't funny like Mrs. Malaprop's mistakes were.  I was tempted to say it, though, so OP would take my point.  But then I decided it might sound hurtful....

Comment: @Josh - I will make sure to use it if I ever find you misusing an idiom, with the confidence that *you* won't take offense.  (It's so hard to know what might bother a stranger on the internet.)

Comment: @Mitch - Pardon me for asking, I just want to verify -- did you look at the referenced question, to get the tricky context?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes

Comment: @Mitch - So do you have a specific suggestion for what to say in that context?

Comment: @aparente001 I thought I gave a list already. Did you want more?

Comment: @Mitch - Comments are ephemeral.  Also, in an answer, I hope to see how you suggest using a proposed word or phrase in the context.  Finally, to tell you the truth I wasn't completely clear whether you were suggesting 'inappropriate', 'just not the way it is said', 'misleading', 'false friend', 'semantic slippage', or rather were suggesting I look for euphemisms for those.  What I really want to know is a polite way of saying to a stranger on ELU that the idiom s/he is suggesting really doesn't work as suggested.  Not in a gentle way, but in a let's-not-loop-on-this-anymore way.

Comment: You could say she is mixing her metaphors, or just being creative with the language. I mix my Italian idioms with English ones, thank the Lord for Google I say :) The other day I wrote comparing apples with pears, when I should have said "oranges" I caught myself in time, and changed the fruit. If I did say something is like comparing apples to pears, would no one have understood?! :))

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I guess the context might have made it clear.  What might make it confusing for someone is the fact that when one hears the word "pear" it might also be "pair." // Sometimes a non-native speaker invents lovely expressions.  My spouse has sometimes lamented the *tougheties* of life.  Children also invent nice things sometimes.  My older son, age three, made up a nice verb in Spanish: choferrear (to drive someone around). // Could you look at the question I referenced to see what you would have recommended in that situation?  ...

Comment: ... The OP (not sure if it was a she) wasn't mixing metaphors in that case, I don't think.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Say the phrasing is not **idiomatic**.

That says you are not judging the words as wrong, but the understanding will be confused because English is particularly idiomatic.

After all, there's no accounting for the idiom in any language. In their English, Spanish speakers say I *have* two years here, I *have* 25 years old, and I *have* two meters tall. English uses I *am*, and the easiest explanation is "It's **idiomatic**:"

> Peculiar to or characteristic of a given language. - [American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic)

Comment: I like this a lot and unless a miracle occurs, will be accepting this.

Comment: Ta da!  I explained to the OP that the proposed phrase wasn't "idiomatically equivalent," and apparently no offense was taken.  Success.

Answer (score 7):

Jeez, when you are making a reference to a comic-relief character in a comedy of manners first produced onstage in 1775, I think you have sort of bottomed-out when it comes to "soft" and "inoffensive".

Perhaps you could [have fun with the idea](http://www.fun-with-words.com/mala_malapropisms.html).  "Not the pineapple of accuracy."  "My affluence over your spoken English is slight."  "Your physiognomy is not grammatical!"

For my own ESL wife, I composed aphorisms to straighten distinctions she reversed.  Like she would confuse "door" and "window", so I taught her "the WIND comes in the WINDOW; the DOg comes in the DOor."

They haven't helped at all but it's only been 28 years, so I'm still hopeful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be gentle you can say that their English is a little unorthodox. Or charming. We native speakers will know what you mean. I once had a French roommate who came home one day and complained that "they really fed me up at school today", which I found quite charming.

If you want to be really nice, you can complement them for their creative use of English.

Answer (score 1):

The phrases are **ambiguous:**

```
open to or having several possible meanings or interpretations; equivocal (dictionary.com)
```

Communicating with terms that can be ambiguous based on context lead to vague perception and can make conversations difficult to follow.

The terms may not be ambiguous from your context, nor are they from your spouse's context, but from the *union of contexts*.

Comment: Are you sure that ambiguous doesn't  carry any potentially offensive connotation?

Comment: Ambiguous should not carry any offensiveness - it usually is assumed unintentional.